# The analogue of the class apex_disabled for hide item in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

If I need to disable item I use *apex_disabled* class.

For example: *$('#myitem').addClass('apex_disabled')*

What class do I need to use to hide the element? *apex_hide* or *apex_hided* does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use JQuery:

```js
$('#myitem').hide();

// revert
$('#myitem').show();
```

Or with a CSS class

```js
$('#myitem').addClass('hidden-lg-down');

//revert
$('#myitem').removeClass('hidden-lg-down');
```

Comment: _**hidden-lg-down**_!!! Tnx!

Can you please tell me where to find it in the APEX documentation?

Comment: Check this [link](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/home)

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/colors This is classes for colors. 

Where is _apex_disabled_, _hidden-lg-down_ and so on?

Comment: I find it! https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/responsive-utilities